# How to upload an image to a Slack Bot using Bolt for JS?

Tags: javascript, file-upload, upload, slack

I'm relatively new to programming and JS, so some guidance would be much appreciated.

Recently, I've made a ***Slack Bot*** using their Bolt for JS library, which has a couple functions:

1. It opens up a modal when you put in a slash command
2. In the modal, it asks for a few inputs (i.e. expense item, expense amount, etc.)
3. I want to include an "***attach image***" button on the modal that allows users to upload an image and send to our backend

I'm not sure how to approach (3).

I have managed to make an "attach image" button and started to look into the files.upload() method from the Slack API.

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around how to make the const ***fileName*** from below dynamic. I want (1) a file selector dialogue to open, (2) the user to be able to select a local file and (3) it's file path to be reflected below.

```
app.action('attach_image_button', async ({ ack, body, logger }) => {
  // Acknowledge the event request
  ack();

  try {
    const team_id = body.view.team_id;
    const fetchAuth = await app.authorize({ teamId: team_id });
    const botToken = fetchAuth.botToken;
    const fileName = './myFileName.gif' <--- HOW DO I MAKE IT SO THAT IT PICKS UP THE FILE PATH OF A FILE THAT THE USER SELECTS? 

    const upload = await app.client.files.upload({ token: botToken, file: createReadStream(fileName) });
    const imageUrl = upload.file.url_private;
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately modals do not support the ability for end users to attach/upload files at this time.